# Why is Python's numpy.polyval() so slow?

Tags: python, numpy

**Update** There was a mistake in the script.

I am working on visualizing Julia & Mandelbrot set and also Newton fractals - for this I need calculating *a lot* of values in the complex plane. I can use any type of mathematical functions I want, but it is enough for polynomials.

I need to calculate the derivative and value of the function/polynomial so I looked into the `numpy` module and found out about `numpy.polyder()` and `numpy.polyval()`. It seemed precisely like the thing I needed, but suddenly my scripts become *very* slow.

I tried to think of some easy test to show the difference in time. For that purpose I wrote the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
import time
from itertools import product

C   = 0.37 + 0.45j
pol = [1,0,0]

start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(100000):
    C = np.polyval(pol, C)

print "Polyval: {}".format( time.time() - start_time )
print C

C   = 0.37 + 0.45j     # forgot to reassign the initial value of C
start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(100000):
    C = C**2

print "Standard: {}".format( time.time() - start_time )
print C
```

Basically this script calculates *a lot* of values for the polynomial g(C) = C**2. The results in time are (the actual output of the program):

```
Polyval: 2.34903216362
0j
Standard: 0.0198249816895
0j
```

I might have not set this test in the best way, doing something like this for the first time. But even if there would be any mistake, running my other scripts show great difference in the time.

#### Question

Is there a way how to make it faster? I understand calling another function is time consuming, but still. Should I rethink the advantage of being able to change the polynomial coefficients only at one place against the disadvantage in time? Any other suggestions on how to deal with such issue?

Comment: I assume you will want to do this for many many values of `C` which live in the unit circle? In that case your second option applied to a grid of complex values should work best. In any case, I am not sure what you are expecting from `polyval`.

Comment: @eickenberg Basically yes, the original script is [here](http://www.math-in-python.com/kvapil/complex_fractals). I would like to run the program for many different polynomials. For instance:
`for pol in [[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1]]:` I did not want to change all the expressions by hand every time.

Comment: [`polyval`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L607) is meant to handle arbitrary polynomials, that in general should not be evaluated in the naive way. x² is a very special case where there is a more direct approach. The good thing, polyval allows vectorized expressions, so you could evaluate all of them at the same time.

Comment: @Davidmh I see. But I am not quite sure about the _evaluate all of them at the same time_ thing. The basic method in constructing those sets is to iterate the function -> f(f(f(f(t)))). I don't see, how to use it here. Sorry, it is late here.

Comment: If I'm getting this right, then you might want to take a look at [numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html), and specifically at the `tensor` parameter.

Comment: Another point is that the test doesn't really show you anything. Surely calling a `numpy` method in a for loop will be slower than calculating x^2 in the said loop. Now if you try to evaluate an arbitrary polynomial at multiple points using a `numpy` solution and a pure python solution, you might get a better estimate of the elapsed times and hence a better comparison.

Comment: @quapka: I think what the other commenters are saying is don't do Python loops over individual pixels, but try to process the image as a whole with Numpy. See e.g. the [Mandelbrot example in the tentative Numpy tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial/Mandelbrot_Set_Example).

Comment: I am sorry I did not respond. The end of semester strikes hard and everywhere, unfortunately there is very little time for experimenting and updating just now. @moarningsun thanks, I understand it quite similarly, but as explained above did not manage to implement it.:-/

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer per se, but I wrote a function `polyval_factory` to generate a `mypolyval` function given an array of coefficients like `pol`. It generates fast expressions like `C*C + 1.0 * C *C*C + 2.0`, in string form, and then bottles them in a lambda function. Basically it uses strings in lieu of a full symbolic algebra library like `sympy`. This function defined, and tested, in the example below, and works almost as fast as `C*C`:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
import time
from itertools import product

def polyval_factory(pol):
    """ 
    Generate a lambda function for evaluating a given polynomial

    pol : a list of coefficients with highest degree first

    Note: this function basically uses strings in lieu of a 
          fully symbolic algebra package like sympy
    """
    poly_string_list = []
    for i, coeff in enumerate(pol[::-1]):

        if np.abs(coeff) > 1e-10:
            if i > 1:
                poly_string_list.append( repr(coeff) + '*' + '*'.join(['x']*i))
            elif i == 1:
                poly_string_list.append(repr(coeff)+'*x')
            elif i ==0:
                poly_string_list.append(repr(coeff))

    lambda_str = 'lambda x :' + '+'.join(poly_string_list)

    print "The prepared lambda function is: \""+lambda_str + "\""

    return eval(lambda_str)

C   = 0.37 + 0.45j
pol = [1,0,0]

numiter  = 30000

start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(numiter):
    C = np.polyval(pol, C)

print "Polyval: {}".format( time.time() - start_time )
print C

C   = 0.37 + 0.45j     # forgot to reassign the initial value of C
print ""
print "Generating lambda function..."
mypolyval = polyval_factory(pol) # generate the lambda function
print ""

start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(numiter):
    C = mypolyval(C)
print "Polyval_factory: {}".format( time.time() - start_time )
print C

C   = 0.37 + 0.45j     # forgot to reassign the initial value of C
print ""
start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(numiter):
    C = C**2
print "Standard: {}".format( time.time() - start_time )
print C
```

The Output is :

```
Polyval: 0.738290071487
0j

Generating lambda function...
The prepared lambda function is: "lambda x :1*x*x"

Polyval_factory: 0.013610124588
0j

Standard: 0.00678110122681
0j
```

**Edit**: `polyval_factory`: now running `mypolyval = polyval_factory([2.0,3.0,1.0])` does the appropriate thing and prints:

```
    The prepared lambda function is: "lambda x :1.0+3.0*x+2.0*x*x"
```

Answer (score 2):

An oddity in the order of multiplication when using the Horner method accounts for a factor of about 5x in speed. This is fixed in numpy 1.10, or you can use `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval`, which is already fixed. It may be possible to vectorize further, for instance by using a 2d array of coefficients in the  `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval` version, but I am not clear on exactly your requirements are. Also note that you can iterate polynomials directly as `p(p)`, but at some point I expect that will cause numerical problems.